# How do I tell MSDeploy to deploy a package using a manifest?

Tags: manifest, msdeploy

I have a TeamCity build that creates a package by running the following:

`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath=C:\path\to\files\myFilesToDeploy -dest:package=C:\path\to\packages\filesToDeployPackage.zip`

Now I want to deploy this package and its contents to a few servers, but I want to do it using a manifest:

`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=C:\path\to\packages\filesToDeployPackage.zip -dest:manifest=C:\path\to\manifests\destManifest.xml`

destManifest.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
    <contentPath path="\\machineNetworkName\path\to\final\content"/>
</sitemanifest>
```

But this gets me the following error:

`Error: Source (contentPath) and destination (sitemanifest) are not compatible for the given operation.`

The only way that I managed to have something work was by having 2 manifests, one for source and one for dest, and use `contentPath` on both XMLs, but then I can't use the package that my build produces. This case requires that folders are uncompressed first. Also I don't like having 2 manifests, I want to solve this with a single manifest.

I've checked Microsoft's docs and other threads and I can't find an example of this. Any hints?

Comment: Can you deploy the package to the contentPath without any manifests?

Comment: @chief7 Yes, if I switch `dest:manifest=[manifest-path]` to `dest:contentPath:[destination-path]` then things work. So I must be building the manifest incorrectly or the msdeploy commands needs to be run differently for my use case. I really want to use a manifest because I might need to specify multiple destinations at a later point. Running that through the command line is a pain. Any idea?